# Return the first object to contain a specific value in a javascript multi level nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an object that contains tasks nested and grouped by weekday. I cannot change its structure. What is the optimal way to return the first task from it that where the value of that task's "status" key !== "complete".

```
    {  
   "total_resource_cost":"20.0",
   "total_unassigned_tasks_count":0,
   "tasks":[  
      {  
         "unassigned_tasks_count":0,
         "resource_cost":"9.0",
         "weekday":"Tuesday",
         "date":"2017-07-11",
         "tasks":[  
            {  
               "id":6196,
               "title":null,
               "category":"Guest Ready Clean",
               "status":"new",
               "date":"2017-07-11",
               "due_date":null,
               "assigned_to":{  
                  "name":"David",
                  "id":2,
                  "mobile":"",
                  "teams":[  

                  ]
               },
               "assigned_to_2":{  
                  "name":"David",
                  "id":2,
                  "mobile":"",
                  "teams":[  

                  ]
               },
               "assigned_to_id":2,
               "assigned_to_2_id":2,
               "team":null,
               "description":null,
               "property":{  
                  "id":114,
                  "code":"WEB-1",
                  "lat":"51.45625339999999",
                  "lng":"-0.16253770000002987",
                  "postal_code":"SW11 6SF"
               },
               "list":null,
               "priority":3,
               "created_by":null,
               "created_at":"2017-07-11T16:39:34.944Z",
               "updated_at":"2017-07-14T14:08:07.082Z",
               "updated_by":{  
                  "id":2,
                  "name":"David",
                  "teams":[  

                  ]
               },
               "notes":null,
               "trigger_rule":"Booking followed by booking.",
               "obsolete":true,
               "resource_cost":"3.0"
            },
            {  
               "id":6228,
               "title":null,
               "category":"Owner Leaving Clean",
               "status":"new",
               "date":"2017-07-11",
               "due_date":null,
               "assigned_to":{  
                  "name":"David the Housekeeper",
                  "id":220,
                  "mobile":"",
                  "teams":[  

                  ]
               },
               "assigned_to_2":{  
                  "name":"David",
                  "id":2,
                  "mobile":"",
                  "teams":[  

                  ]
               },
               "assigned_to_id":220,
               "assigned_to_2_id":2,
               "team":null,
               "description":null,
               "property":{  
                  "id":245,
                  "code":"ROL-1",
                  "lat":"51.51190219999999",
                  "lng":"-0.03558299999997416",
                  "postal_code":"E14 7JA"
               },
               "list":null,
               "priority":3,
               "created_by":null,
               "created_at":"2017-07-11T16:39:39.895Z",
               "updated_at":"2017-07-14T14:07:58.565Z",
               "updated_by":{  
                  "id":2,
                  "name":"David",
                  "teams":[  

                  ]
               },
               "notes":null,
               "trigger_rule":"Booking following block.",
               "obsolete":true,
               "resource_cost":"2.5"
            },
            {  
               "id":6207,
               "title":null,
               "category":"Guest Ready Clean",
               "status":"new",
               "date":"2017-07-11",
               "due_date":null,
               "assigned_to":{  
                  "name":"David the Housekeeper",
                  "id":220,
                  "mobile":"",
                  "teams":[  

                  ]
               },
               "assigned_to_2":{  
                  "name":"David",
                  "id":2,
                  "mobile":"",
                  "teams":[  

                  ]
               },
               "assigned_to_id":220,
               "assigned_to_2_id":2,
               "team":null,
               "description":null,
               "property":{  
                  "id":126,
                  "code":"PRO-1",
                  "lat":"51.5375129",
                  "lng":"-0.042265000000043074",
                  "postal_code":"E9 7DS"
               },
               "list":null,
               "priority":3,
               "created_by":null,
               "created_at":"2017-07-11T16:39:35.963Z",
               "updated_at":"2017-07-14T14:07:54.920Z",
               "updated_by":{  
                  "id":2,
                  "name":"David",
                  "teams":[  

                  ]
               },
               "notes":null,
               "trigger_rule":"Booking followed by booking.",
               "obsolete":true,
               "resource_cost":"2.0"
            },
            {  
               "id":6202,
               "title":null,
               "category":"Guest Ready Clean",
               "status":"new",
               "date":"2017-07-11",
               "due_date":null,
               "assigned_to":{  
                  "name":"David",
                  "id":2,
                  "mobile":"",
                  "teams":[  

                  ]
               },
               "assigned_to_2":{  
                  "name":"David the Housekeeper",
                  "id":220,
                  "mobile":"+",
                  "teams":[  

                  ]
               },
               "assigned_to_id":2,
               "assigned_to_2_id":220,
               "team":null,
               "description":null,
               "property":{  
                  "id":234,
                  "code":"CAD-2",
                  "lat":"51.4924164",
                  "lng":"-0.16394930000001295",
                  "postal_code":"SW3 2PP"
               },
               "list":null,
               "priority":3,
               "created_by":null,
               "created_at":"2017-07-11T16:39:35.307Z",
               "updated_at":"2017-07-14T14:07:49.911Z",
               "updated_by":{  
                  "id":2,
                  "name":"David",
                  "teams":[  

                  ]
               },
               "notes":null,
               "trigger_rule":"Booking followed by booking.",
               "obsolete":true,
               "resource_cost":"1.5"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "unassigned_tasks_count":0,
         "resource_cost":"11.0",
         "weekday":"Wednesday",
         "date":"2017-07-12",
         "tasks":[  
            {  
               "id":6148,
               "title":null,
               "category":"Guest Ready Clean",
               "status":"new",
               "date":"2017-07-12",
               "due_date":null,
               "assigned_to":{  
                  "name":"David",
                  "id":2,
                  "mobile":"",
                  "teams":[  

                  ]
               },
               "assigned_to_2":null,
               "assigned_to_id":2,
               "assigned_to_2_id":null,
               "team":null,
               "description":null,
               "property":{  
                  "id":116,
                  "code":"SAR-1",
                  "lat":null,
                  "lng":null,
                  "postal_code":null
               },
               "list":null,
               "priority":3,
               "created_by":null,
               "created_at":"2017-07-11T16:39:28.736Z",
               "updated_at":"2017-07-14T15:30:15.665Z",
               "updated_by":{  
                  "id":2,
                  "name":"David",
                  "teams":[  

                  ]
               },
               "notes":null,
               "trigger_rule":"Booking followed by booking.",
               "obsolete":true,
               "resource_cost":"5.5"
            },
            {  
               "id":6193,
               "title":null,
               "category":"Guest Ready Clean",
               "status":"new",
               "date":"2017-07-12",
               "due_date":null,
               "assigned_to":{  
                  "name":"David",
                  "id":2,
                  "mobile":"",
                  "teams":[  

                  ]
               },
               "assigned_to_2":null,
               "assigned_to_id":2,
               "assigned_to_2_id":null,
               "team":null,
               "description":null,
               "property":{  
                  "id":216,
                  "code":"MAC-1",
                  "lat":"51.5480904",
                  "lng":"-0.11545330000001286",
                  "postal_code":"N7 8QY"
               },
               "list":null,
               "priority":3,
               "created_by":null,
               "created_at":"2017-07-11T16:39:34.435Z",
               "updated_at":"2017-07-14T15:30:03.989Z",
               "updated_by":{  
                  "id":2,
                  "name":"David",
                  "teams":[  

                  ]
               },
               "notes":null,
               "trigger_rule":"A stay has ended. Unclear what the next event is.",
               "obsolete":true,
               "resource_cost":"3.5"
            },
            {  
               "id":6238,
               "title":null,
               "category":"Guest Ready Clean",
               "status":"new",
               "date":"2017-07-12",
               "due_date":null,
               "assigned_to":{  
                  "name":"David",
                  "id":2,
                  "mobile":"",
                  "teams":[  

                  ]
               },
               "assigned_to_2":null,
               "assigned_to_id":2,
               "assigned_to_2_id":null,
               "team":null,
               "description":null,
               "property":{  
                  "id":252,
                  "code":"WEL-1",
                  "lat":"51.4853737",
                  "lng":"0.03197999999997592",
                  "postal_code":"SE7 7PH"
               },
               "list":null,
               "priority":3,
               "created_by":null,
               "created_at":"2017-07-11T16:39:40.933Z",
               "updated_at":"2017-07-14T15:29:53.195Z",
               "updated_by":{  
                  "id":2,
                  "name":"David",
                  "teams":[  

                  ]
               },
               "notes":null,
               "trigger_rule":"Booking followed by booking.",
               "obsolete":true,
               "resource_cost":"2.0"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slight improvement over Abhishek Soni's answer. Rather than filtering on all complete tasks, we can use `.find` to return the first item in the array that returns true.

```
const firstCompletedTasked = response.tasks[0].tasks.find(task => task.status === 'complete');
```

Comment: Out if interest could you please explain why this is an improvement? Speed?

Comment: Speed is a small factor, as find will return as soon it finds a match, whereas filter will process the whole array. The big thing for me is that find is going to return the object, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you save that object in a variable named `response`:

```
let firstInCompleteTask = response.tasks[0].tasks.filter((task)=>{
  return task.status !== 'complete'
})[0];
```

Also, the first `tasks` Array has two objects, which then have a tasks array in them. The code above returns the first incomplete task from the first Object.

If you want incomplete tasks from both the objects, you'll have to use something like:

```
let incompleteTasks = [];
for(i = 0; i < response.tasks.length; i++){
    let firstInCompleteTask = response.tasks[i].tasks.filter((task)=>{
      return task.status !== 'complete'
    })[0];

    incompleteTasks.push(fistInCompleteTask);
}
```